# Is there a way to paste together the elements of a vector in R without using a loop?

Tags: r, paste, memory-efficient

Say there's a vector x:

```
x <- c("a", " ", "b")
```

and I want to quickly turn this into a single string "a b". Is there a way to do this without a loop? I know with a loop I could do this:

```
y <- ""
for (i in 1:3){
    paste(y, x[i], sep = "")
}

> y
[1] "a b"
```

but I will need to do this over many, many iterations, and having to loop over this and replace the original with the new each time would become very time consuming. I always want to be able to do something like this:

```
x <- paste(x)
```

as if paste() could smartly divide up the elements of a vector itself, but I know it can't. Is there another function, or a more creative way to use paste(), which can accomplish this efficiently?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You just need to use the `collapse` argument:

```
paste(x,collapse="")
```

Comment: Thank you! I kept thinking there should be something called "collapse" involved in this, but I couldn't find any documentation on it.

Comment: It's right there in `?paste`! ;) If you're ever confused about a function type `?function` in the console to access the help files.

Comment: Yeah guess it didn't occur to me that it'd be an argument of paste. Just when you think you know a function...:P

Comment: R help files are remarkably helpful, even if it isn't an argument of the function you might just find the function you are looking for:)

Comment: You can use ```paste(str_pad(l,width=7,side="left"), collapse = "")```

Answer (score 7):

Just adding a `tidyverse` way to provide an alternative to using `paste()`:

```r
library(glue)
x <- c("a", " ", "b")
glue_collapse(x)
#> a b
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>