# pasting several rows into 1 row separated by ";" in R

Tags: r, dataframe

i have got about 150k rows and 1 col, some rows have more than 1 word so  what i need to do is to get all the rows "concatenated" into 1 row and separated by a `;` 
this is what i have got now:

`Client
 1      John S
 2      Carl
 3      Katy Smith
 4      J P Morgan Stanley`

what i need to see is:

`Client
John S;Carl;Katy Smith;J P Morgan Stanley`

i have tried:

`paste(Client, sep = '', collapse = ';')` but it does not work.

help please?

Comment: Is `Client` a `data.frame`? You need to pass in a vector to `paste`

Comment: paste(df[,1], sep = '', collapse = ';')

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698839/is-there-a-way-to-paste-together-the-elements-of-a-vector-in-r-without-using-a-l) is pretty similar to yours.

Comment: @jazzurro i have explained my reasons for posting this question as i am a novice in the field.

Comment: @RaulGonzales I understand your situation. There are a tons of questions on SO. If you type with a few key words for your task you would be able to find an answer or a hint. Would you be able to do that from next time before you ask? If you really cannot find any relevant question, you can ask for a help. :)

Comment: @jazzurro thanks for that! i struggle to explain myself sometimes although i know exactly what i want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("John S", "Carl", "Katy Smith", "J P Morgan Stanley")) 
paste(df$x, collapse = ";")

[1] "John S;Carl;Katy Smith;J P Morgan Stanley"
```